# Firefox box shadow much lighter in latest build

Tags: html, css, firefox, box-shadow

I'm finding that Firefox (44.0.2) is rendering the box-shadow CSS very faint / light.

If you compare the difference between Chrome and Firefox it looks a lot lighter in Firefox.
https://jsfiddle.net/8db8zr6q/

I was wondering if anyone has come across this problem before and if there is anything that can be done to fix the issue?

Current code:

```
.shadow {
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 101px -52px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 101px -52px rgba(0,0,0,1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px -200px 101px -52px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

Image of issue:

[image]

Comment: Firefox appears to be (incorrectly) clipping the inset shadow based on the dimensions of the box. The spread radius also seems off.

Comment: @BoltClock can you verify that you are saying about firefox with a W3C definition? https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-css3-background-20100612/box-shadow.src.html I think there is very injustice with firefox's behaviours when the most times is chrome making that google wants instead the standard recommendations. Thank you.

Comment: @Marcos Pérez Gude: From https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#shadow-shape (not sure why you're linking to an older draft): "An inner box-shadow casts a shadow as if everything outside the padding edge were opaque." That means no clipping ("knockout") should occur whatsoever. In this example, it means there should not be a second gradient near the bottom edge of the box as shown in Firefox - it should be solid black, as shown in Chrome.

Comment: That's clear now. In this case you're right. Thank you!!!

Comment: It looks as if the issue is down to the inset property. If I remove inset the shadow is darker. Although it doesn't help me much as I need the inset value! I should also say that it works fine in IE and other Firefox versions.. the previous version I was on (43.0.1) rendered the box-shadow fine.

Comment: I'm using FF 47 and I can verify there is no problem and the render is consistent with Chrome's. This was probably a bug. http://i.imgur.com/6gxWDko.jpg

Comment: bit hacky, but could be a workaround for you: https://jsfiddle.net/8db8zr6q/5.  I think the bug is with using the negative spread radius with inset

Comment: I saw this issue in only firefox 44. previous firefox versions works fine

Comment: Firefox 45.0.1 compared to Chrome 49.0.2623.87, they seem almost identical. Definitely not lighter in Firefox, like your screenshot. The Firefox shadow does seem to have more of a "blur" (softness) to the shadows. But as far as darkness, they appear the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and after long research i found no straight answer so the work around hack is used was to target the -moz-box-shadow prefix by playing around with the values till i got the shade I wanted ,when developing websites i found firefox renders certain things way differently than what you intend

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? Your answer is more like a comment as it is.